# How could a function look like, that can add an other function to a list of functions that run parallel in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
def update():
   while True:
       loadData()

def main():
   doStuff()
   addToParallelFunctions(update)
   doOtherStuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   addToParallelFunctions(main)
```

How could that `addToParallelFunctions` function look like, so that update runs parallel to `main` and that I can add other functions to run also parallel to the `main`?

I've tried that, but it paused the main function and ran the other function until she was finished.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def addProcess(*funcs):
    for func in funcs:
       Process(target=func).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I enhanced your example:
It works for me. Main script and function continue both.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def addProcess(*funcs):
    for func in funcs:
       Process(target=func).start()

def update():
   for i in range(20):
       print(i)
       time.sleep(2)

def main():
   print("start")
   addProcess(update)
   print("Main function continues")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   addProcess(main)
   print("main script continues")
```

Next time, please post an example that is reproducible.

Comment: I found the mistake I don't now we it worked for you but I had to call the ```main()``` method like this else it didn't works for me.